# how to do arithmetic between IntegerProperty and int

Tags: python, google-app-engine

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        user_spot = parking()
        user_spot.location_X = payload['location_X']
        user_spot.location_Y = payload['location_Y']               
        query = None
        query = parking.query(parking.location_X - 10>= user_spot.location_X ,parking.location_X + 10 <= user_spot.location_X)
```

i'm tring to run this query but i can't since int and integer property are not the same

any idea on how to?

Answer (score 1):

ok i found the solotion
query = parking.query(parking.location_X 10>= user_spot.location_X -10 ,parking.location_X <= user_spot.location_X+10) 
just move the arithmetic to the int